# How to draw two rectangles next to eachother on a print page? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm looking to print two graphs on the same page. Muy current code only displays one graph on the print page. Could anyone poij tme in the right direction as to how i can draw the second graph directly underneath the first graph?

Code:

```
 Private Sub PrintBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintBtn.Click
    PrintDialog.PrinterSettings = PrintDoc.PrinterSettings
    If PrintDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintDoc.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog.PrinterSettings

        Dim PageSetup As New PageSettings
        With PageSetup
            .Margins.Left = 50
            .Margins.Right = 50
            .Margins.Top = 50
            .Margins.Bottom = 50
            .Landscape = False
        End With
        PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings = PageSetup

    End If
    PrintPreviewDialog.Document = PrintDoc
    PrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog()
End Sub

'Call print function in our custom LineGraph class
Private Sub PrintDoc_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage
    BPGraph.PrintToGraphics(e.Graphics, e.MarginBounds)
    HRGraph.PrintToGraphics(e.Graphics, e.MarginBounds)
End Sub
```

Comment: The `.PrintToGraphics` method is supplied with `e.MarginBounds`. You could work out how to supply it with the area you want to print it on instead of the whole page, maybe the top half and bottom half.

Comment: That's a great Idea Andrew, do you have any tips on how to go about that?

Comment: For the second graph, you should add some offset to `e.MarginBounds` for the two graphs not to overlap each other.

Comment: Without setting up anything for me to test with, something like `Dim topHalf = New Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height \ 2)` `Dim bottomHalf = New Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Bottom \ 2, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height \ 2)` `BPGraph.PrintToGraphics(e.Graphics, topHalf)` `HRGraph.PrintToGraphics(e.Graphics, bottomHalf)`. I may have the coordinates upside down.